# How to run Apache as non-root user?

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile, containers, root

I'm building an image from the following Dockerfile and following command `docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t non_root_image_plz_work .`:

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:14.7.0-buster-slim AS apache_for_selenium

# Create non-root group and user
RUN addgroup --system shared-folder \
&& adduser --system --home /var/cache/shared-folder --group shared-folder --uid 1001

# Make Port accessable 
EXPOSE 80/tcp

# Set Node env.Name
ENV NODE_ENV=dev 

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends nano git openssl bash musl curl apache2 apache2-utils systemd && \
    systemctl enable apache2 && npm config set registry http://localhost:5000/repository/repo && \
    npm i -g pm2 serve && mkdir /usr/share/shared-folder

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log    

WORKDIR /usr/share/shared-folder 

COPY . /usr/share/shared-folder/

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify && \
    rm /var/www/html/index.html && \
    ln -s /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && \
    chown www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && chgrp www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report 

VOLUME /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report

USER 1001

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "service apache2 start ; pm2-runtime process.yml --no-daemon" ]
```

When I try to run the image using `docker run non_root_image_plz_work`, I get the following error:

**Error after running `docker run` command:**
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2 failed!
The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Output of config test was:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.3FGoa8Y71E': Operation not permitted

It seems to be a permissions issue, as if I'm not properly running the container as a non-root user. Any suggestions on how I can get the container to run properly as a non-root user?

**Note:** I used a dummy registry in the Dockerfile for I don't want to show the actual registry, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Docker, all folders are owned by `root`. Without knowing your directory structure, I guess your problem is, that your user *1001* (or the setup programm which is run with `1001`'s permission) tries to access directories that (probably) are owned by `root`.

*Either you can try:*

1. Change your permissions of the folders.

   This can be used of you know which folders are accessed and want to prevent further permission issues.

   ```sh
   chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder
   ```
2. Give your user proper permissions.

   Here is a **very quick** walkthrough. Please comment if it didn't slove your problem and I'll try to update this for a more specific answer.

   A small example (taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296533/sudo-inside-docker-on-fedora-ask-for-password-on-host-it-doesnt-ask-password)).
   You can setup your non-root-user `foo` with passwordless access:

   ```sh
   RUN \
       groupadd -g 1001 foo && useradd -u 1001 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash 1001 
   && \
       sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
       sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
       sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
       echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers;  su - foo -c id
   ```

   *Hint:* You will probably need to install `sudo`

   ```sh
   apt-get install sudo
   ```

   Now, try running the *entrypoint* (or your commad) with `sudo`.

---

EDIT:
I've updated the answer to match your Docker-File. Have a look at it. The user nonroot is assigned uuid *1001* and added to `/etc/sudoers`. Also your command is now run with sudo which should prevent the permission issues.

```
FROM node:14.7.0-buster-slim AS apache_for_selenium

# Create non-root group and user
RUN addgroup --system shared-folder \
    && adduser --system --home /var/cache/shared-folder --ingroup shared-folder --uid 1001 nonroot

# Make Port accessable 
EXPOSE 80/tcp

# Set Node env.Name
ENV NODE_ENV=dev 

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo nano git openssl bash musl curl apache2 apache2-utils systemd \
    && systemctl enable apache2 
    #\
    # && #npm config set registry http://localhost:5000/repository/repo && \
    #npm i -g pm2 serve && mkdir /usr/share/shared-folder

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log    

WORKDIR /usr/share/shared-folder 

COPY . /usr/share/shared-folder/

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify && \
    rm /var/www/html/index.html && \
    ln -s /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && \
    chown www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && chgrp www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report 

VOLUME /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report

RUN \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "nonroot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER nonroot
CMD [ "sudo sh", "-c", "service apache2 start ; pm2-runtime process.yml --no-daemon" ]
```

Comment: I get this error when i try running the container from the suggested changes above: Error: Cannot find module '/usr/share/shared-folder/sudo sh'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: did you install sudo via apt-get?

Comment: And why not using an entrypoint-script instaed of docker's weird splitted commands? -> `ENTRYPINT [ '/entrypoint.sh' ]`

Comment: yes i did, i added it to the end of the second RUN command. Also, is there a reason to comment out the lines that contain # && #npm config set registry http://localhost:5000/repository/repo && \
    #npm i -g pm2 serve && mkdir /usr/share/shared-folder?? I have it set to a private repo, i just used the 'localhost' as a placeholder

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `apache`, but I don't think it's a permission issue. The only possibility I can think of is to try `CMD [ "sudo", "sh", "-c", "service apache2 start ; pm2-runtime process.yml --no-daemon" ]` but that's just a guess. 
Can you try to run the whole command in an entrypoint script as I suggested?

Comment: commeted lines: No  I just commented them out because otherwise docker wasn't able to build the image (as you said, they are just placeholders)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220821/discussion-between-agentsmith-and-losercoder2345).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here: apache is special user. it only can start by root user.
you can not start apache by another user. That why you got permission deny.
Seen i saw your dockerfile. your user created is normal user.

Try make script like below with name apache-start :

```
    #!/bin/sh
set -e
# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid
exec httpd -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

and your docker file should be like

```
FROM node:14.7.0-buster-slim AS apache_for_selenium
# Create non-root group and user
RUN addgroup --system shared-folder \
&& adduser --system --home /var/cache/shared-folder --group shared-folder --uid 1001
# Make Port accessable 
EXPOSE 80/tcp
# Set Node env.Name
ENV NODE_ENV=dev 
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends nano git openssl bash musl curl apache2 apache2-utils systemd && \
    systemctl enable apache2 && npm config set registry http://localhost:5000/repository/repo && \
    npm i -g pm2 serve && mkdir /usr/share/shared-folder
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log    
WORKDIR /usr/share/shared-folder 
COPY . /usr/share/shared-folder/
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify && \
    rm /var/www/html/index.html && \
    ln -s /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && \
    chown www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report && chgrp www-data -R /var/www/html/mochawesome-report 
VOLUME /usr/share/shared-folder/mochawesome-report
COPY apache-start /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["apache-start"]
USER 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to switch to [podman](https://github.com/containers/podman) tool which is an alternative to Docker. With podman you can run containers (the same images you use in Docker) but with normal users. That has a lot of benefits specially from security point of view.